# How to find the current activity of an app in ios

Tags: appium-ios

I am using Appium for IOS testing. (java) I want to be able to check the current activity of an app . In the sense when an App switches from clickable to another (say I close the app or switch to another app or open the notifications scroll. I want to be able to detect the page name. To get the current activity name, i use driver.currentActivity(); which is included in the AndroidDriver class.

but There is no direct call for current package in ios, but many suggested that can be found out by looking at the attributes of existing elements in the device screen by calling driver.getPageSource(); how  can I achieve this using driver.getPageSource or is there any other way to do it?Any advise on this would be helpful.

Comment: Currently appium is not supporting switching between app, because Apple's XCUITest is not provided the feature. However, Xcode 9 and iOS 11, apple provided the action to switch to app in xcodebuild command. So we can expect the Appium will provide the support in future for switching  apps. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi, I'm not trying to switch apps. My question: is it possible to get the current activity using appium for ios and how to find the clickable items?

Comment: iOS is not having concept of activity and you have to use some unique element to identify the page/screen

Comment: could you please share any working example. That would be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, Each page on iOS app has Navigation bar on top and it has the screen/page name (navigation title). Use the xpath //XCUIElementTypeNavigationBar/XCUIElementTypeStaticText to get the text of page title and compare with your predefined page.

Comment: Hi, Few screens doesn't have a navigation title. what needs to be done in that scenario. How do i know the widgets in that particular screen?

Comment: Hi, find an unique element (use ID, xpath, name )on that page and use that as a reference of the page .

Answer (score 1):

You can query current app state, if you have the bundleId of the app then you can
query it's state if its running in background or foreground and it solves your problem.

```java
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("bundleId", "com.myapp");
final int state = (Integer)js.executeScript("mobile: queryAppState", params);
```

There can be 5 possible state as per the documentation.

```
0: The current application state cannot be determined/is unknown
1: The application is not running
2: The application is running in the background and is suspended
3: The application is running in the background and is not suspended
4: The application is running in the foreground
```

[Refrences](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/ios/ios-xctest-mobile-apps-management/index.html#mobile-activateapp)

Answer (score 0):

To see if your app is running, assuming you know the bundleId, you can use the driver directly:

```
driver.queryAppState('com.apple.Preferences');
```

It returns the ApplicationState:

```
NOT_INSTALLED,
NOT_RUNNING, 
RUNNING_IN_BACKGROUND_SUSPENDED,
RUNNING_IN_BACKGROUND, 
RUNNING_IN_FOREGROUND
```